# gwt : URL was not found. eclpse/

Tags: eclipse, url, gwt, service

What i have to do to proper run my app under eclipse as a web app ?

My application is working fine under tomcat but when i start this in eclipse using 'run as web app' then i've got many massages like this :
'

The requested URL /com.xxx.xxx.xxx/xxxx was not found on this server.

'

Those messages are from firebug plugin.

please help.

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse check **Run Configuration** .

Do right click of project : Run As->Run Configuration->Web Application->Arguments

> -remoteUI "${gwt_remote_ui_server_port}:${unique_id}" -startupUrl Gwtdevtest.html -logLevel INFO -codeServerPort 9997 -port 8888 -war D:\project_backup\sample-workspace2.0\gwtdevtest\war com.test.gwtdev.Gwtdevtest

As per your project path and module, do changes in arguments.